# Positive lookbehind, slice words by \t until \n

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex.  I am attempting to use regex with python to find a line in a file and extract all of the subsequent words separated by tab stops. My line looks like this.

```
#position   4450    4452    4455    4465    4476    4496    D110    D111    D112    D114    D116    D118    D23 D24 D27 D29 D30 D56 D59 D69 D85 D88 D90 D91 JW1 JW10    JW15    JW22    JW28    JW3 JW35    JW39    JW43    JW45    JW47    JW49    JW5 JW52    JW54    JW56    JW57    JW59    JW66    JW7 JW70    JW75    JW77    JW9 REF_OR74A
```

I have identified that the base of this expression involves the positive lookbehind.

```
(?<=#position).*
```

I do not expect this to separate the matches by tabstop. However, it does find my line in the file:

```
import re

file = open('src.txt','r')
f = list(file)
file.close()

pattern = '(?<=#position).*'
regex = re.compile(pattern)

regex.findall(''.join(f))
['\t4450\t4452\t4455\t4465\t4476\t4496\tD110\tD111\tD112\tD114\tD116\tD118\tD23\tD24\tD27\tD29\tD30\tD56\tD59\tD69\tD85\tD88\tD90\tD91\tJW1\tJW10\tJW15\tJW22\tJW28\tJW3\tJW35\tJW39\tJW43\tJW45\tJW47\tJW49\tJW5\tJW52\tJW54\tJW56\tJW57\tJW59\tJW66\tJW7\tJW70\tJW75\tJW77\tJW9\tREF_OR74A']
```

With some kludge and list slicing / string methods, I can manipulate this and get my data out.  What I'd really like to do is have findall yield a list of just these entries.  What would the regular expression look like to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to use regex? List slicing and string methods don't appear to be as much of a kludge as you say.

something like:

```
f = open('src.txt','r')
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("#position"):
        l = line.split()  # with no arguments it splits on all whitespace characters
        l = l[1:]         # get rid of the "#position" tag
        break
```

and further manipulate from there?

Comment: Or if `'#position'` is in the middle of the line, `if '#position' in line: l = line.split('#position')[-1].split()[1:]`